Multiple Windows 10 hosts are unable to form a Docker Swarm cluster
I have three Windows 10 computers, each with Docker Desktop installed. I'm trying to set up a Docker Swarm cluster with these three computers.
After executing docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.122.85.22:2377 --listen-addr 127.0.0.1:2377 on the master node, when I run docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-64w95ljui02pludj0c55a4ranlq1c2njjx5zx4g1xmgimubdux-f41q73azm53bubmsxp7emssxy 10.122.85.22:2377 on the worker nodes, it consistently times out.
Could someone please help me understand the reason behind this timeout issue?
I have executed the following commands on the master node and also disabled the firewall:
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="swm 2377" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=2377
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="swm 7946" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=7946
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="swm 7946udp" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=7946
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="swm 4789" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4789
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="swm 4789udp" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=4789
However, the worker nodes are still unable to join the Docker Swarm
If I change the command to docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.122.85.22:2377 --listen-addr 0.0.0.0:2377, I encounter the following error: "Error response from daemon: must specify a listening address because the address to advertise is not recognized as a system address, and a system's IP address to use could not be uniquely identified"
